# API with authentication - signature in response?

Tags: authentication, restful-authentication

I have an API where the client calling in must include a signature. This is based on similar to oauth and how amazon do it (signature v2)
My question is is the default standard to also add a signature in the response going back to the client?

Comment: Have a look at token-based systems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have looked at other APIs like twitter and Amazon. They do not add authentication  details in the response to the client